Python post multiple file with aiohttp
I I designed a microservice architecture and I want to post a request from one fastapi service to another fastapi service and retrieve a file as response via aiohttp.
1st service:
from __future__ import annotations

import json
from typing import Dict
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector, FormData

class HttpClient:
    session: ClientSession = None
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

    @staticmethod
    async def start(
        *args,
        headers=None,
        json_serialize=lambda obj, **kwargs: json.dumps(obj, default=str, **kwargs),
        raise_for_status=True,
        connector_parameters: Dict = None,
        **kwargs
    ):
        if headers is None:
            headers = HttpClient.headers

        if connector_parameters is None:
            connector_parameters = {}

        connector = TCPConnector(**connector_parameters)
        HttpClient.session = ClientSession(headers=headers,
                                           json_serialize=json_serialize,
                                           raise_for_status=raise_for_status,
                                           connector=connector,
                                           **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    async def stop():
        await HttpClient.session.close()
        HttpClient.session = None

    @staticmethod
    async def restart(*args, **kwargs):
        await HttpClient.stop()
        await HttpClient.start(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self) -> ClientSession:
        assert HttpClient.session is not None, "Session not found. Please start or restart session."
        return HttpClient.session


client = HttpClient()
app = FastAPI()

async def call_second_service(files: list[UploadFile]):
    try:
        data = FormData()
        for file in files:
            data.add_field('files', file.file, filename=file.filename, content_type=file.content_type)
        async with client().post(url="second_service_url/upload", data=data) as response:
            response_file = await response.read()
            return response_file
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    await client.start()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await client.stop()

@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(files: Annotated[list[UploadFile], File(description="Upload files")]):
    return await call_second_service(files)

2nd service upload endpoint:

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload_file(files: Annotated[list[UploadFile], File(description="Files")]):
    continue

When using the python requests library, everything works correctly, but when I use aiohttp client(), I get error 422. What is the reason of this?
Error Message:
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 411, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 69, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 758, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 778, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 299, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 79, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 74, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 278, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/src/__init__.py", line 78, in upload
    return await call_second_service(files)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/src/__init__.py", line 63, in call_second_service
    raise e
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/src/__init__.py", line 59, in call_second_service
    async with client().post(url="http://localhost:8003/ocr/convert-file", data=data) as response:
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1194, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 693, in _request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/furkankyildirim/Desktop/ocr-gateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1060, in raise_for_status
    raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 422, message='Unprocessable Entity', url=URL('http://localhost:8003/upload')


I doubt this is the issue, but if you're expecting a file to come back, why would you Accept: application/json?

I am using Accept: application/json for generic usage on HttpClientclass.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

how do you use aiohttp client()? Show it in question (not in comments)

I added error message. Also, I already showed client() usage

Does this answer your question?

Please have a look at related answers here, as well as here and here
